# Most efficient way to get nearby android devices

Tags: android, performance, gps

Is there a way to group android devices registered with my app, say within a radius of 30meters.

I have tried saving GPS location of current device say **X**, with polling *(issue: consumes data and power)*, and then retrieving a list of devices whose radial distance with the device **X** is less than 30meters.

The issue with GPS is, it isn't very accurate at times, when it comes to such small radial distances.

Also, let's say device **Y** is at 29meters (boundary for X's group) from **X**, it should fall inside the group of X, instead of making a group of its own.

Any valuable insight on how to efficiently tackle this situation, would be of great help.

Comment: Another option might be Bluetooth LE possibly with [Google Nearby technologies](https://developers.google.com/nearby/). Most Android device can scan for other Bluetooth LE devices, but unfortunately only some models can "advertise" themselves i.e. actually broadcast a message like an iBeacon or Eddystone beacon. Even with BLE the distance won't be very accurate, can be off by several meters and can fluctuate. Of course small fluctuation is something that you should take into account in your code and allow some tolerance maybe with some sort of hysteresis: enter region at 30 m, leave it at 35.

Comment: Thanks Markus, quite valuable suggestion,Google Nearby Tech, looks interesting. Will explore it out.